# Getting error in moodle 2.4 after a year

Tags: php, moodle

I had moodle 2.4 working perfectly well for about 1 and half year on VPS. All other applications are working fine except moodle. Suddenly since yesterday I have started getting following error:

Warning: require_once(/home/mydomain/public_html/moodle24/config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mydomain/public_html/moodle24/index.php on line 31

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mydomain/public_html/moodle24/index.php on line 31

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: *Permission denied* set rights for reading etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the config.php was edited on the server so now the ownership has changed.

If you have ssh access then check the ownership of the files in the folder.

```
ssh yourhost
cd /yourwwwmoodlefolder/
ls -lhrt
```

This will show the ownership of all the files in the folder. They will probably be www-data www-data - except for config.php which will be something different.

If the rest of the files are www-data www-data then just run

```
chown www-data:www-data config.php
```